# fastest way to compute scalar product of an ensemble of vectors

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parallel-computing, fourier-transform

I have an ensemble of points in 3D space, represented by their coordinates $\mathbf{c_i}\equiv(x_i,y_i,z_i)^\top$ . I need to calculate

- the distance between all these points: $\quad\forall i,j\quad d_{ij} \equiv |\mathbf{d_{ij}}|\equiv |\mathbf{c_j}-\mathbf{c_i}|$
- the scalar product between all distances that share a common coordinate. $\quad\forall i,j,k\quad \mathbf{d_{ij}}\cdot\mathbf{d_{ik}}$

What is the fastest way to do this on a single thread? Is Fourier space going to be of any use? Can it be parallelized to make it even faster? If approximations are proposed, they should come with an error bound.

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate the distance between *all* pairs of points?  Would it be enough to compute the distance only between pairs of points that are relatively close to each other (but not for pairs of points that are very far away)?  How do you want the results to be represented?  If you want a list of all of these numbers, then obviously $\Theta(n^3)$ is the best you can do, since the output is of size $\Theta(n^3)$.